# web scraping failure of log in using python requests module

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am trying to develop a script with python to web scraping some information on a specific website for learning purposes.
I went over a lot of different tutorials and posts, trying to gather some insights from them, they are very useful but still didn't help me to find a way to log in the website and do searches with different keywords.

I tried to use different APIs, such as `requests` and `urllib`, maybe I didn't find the right way to solve it.

## The steps lists as follow:

login information set up

Send login information to the website and get response for future use

keywords setup

import header

set up cookiejar

from login response, do the search

After I tried, it will work randomly, and

## here is the code:

```
import getpass
# marvin
# date:2018/2/7

# login stage preparation
def login_values():
    login="https://www.****.com/login"
    username = input("Please insert your username: ") 
    password = getpass.getpass("Please type in your password: ")
    host="www.****.com"
    #store login screts
    data = {
        "username": username, 
        "password": password, 
    }
    return login,host,data
```

The following is for getting the HTML file from a website

```
import requests
import random
import http.cookiejar
import socket
# Set up web scraping function to output the html text file
def webscrape(login_url,host_url,login_data,target_url):
    #static values preparation
    ##import header
    user_agents = [
                ***
                ] 
    agent = random.choice(user_agents)
    headers={'User-agent':agent,
            'Accept':'*/*',
             'Accept-Language':'en-US,en;q=0.9;zh-cmn-Hans',
             'Host':host_url,
             'charset':'utf-8',
            }
    ##set up cookie jar
    cj = http.cookiejar.CookieJar()
    #
    # get the html file
    socket.setdefaulttimeout(20)
    s=requests.Session()
    req=s.post(login_url, data=login_data)
    res = s.get(target_url, cookies=cj,headers=headers)
    html=res.text
    return html
```

## Here is the code to get each links from html:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


#set up html parsing function for parsing all the list links
def getlist(keyword,loginurl,hosturl,valuesurl,html_lists):
    page=1
    pagenum=10# set up maximum page num
    links=[]
    soup=BeautifulSoup(html_lists,"lxml")
    try:
        for li in soup.find("div",class_="search_pager human_pager in-block").ul.find_all('li'):
            target_part=soup.find_all("div",class_="search_result_single search-2017 pb25 pt25 pl30 pr30 ")
            [links.append(link.find('a')['href']) for link in target_part]
            page+=1
            if page<=pagenum:
                    try:
                        nexturl=soup.find('div',class_='search_pager human_pager in-block').ul.find('li',class_='pagination-next ng-scope ').a['href'] #next page
                    except AttributeError:
                        print("{}'s links are all stored!".format(keyword))
                        return links
                    else:
                        chs_html=webscrape(loginurl,hosturl,valuesurl,nexturl)
                        soup=BeautifulSoup(chs_html,"lxml")
    except AttributeError:
        target_part=soup.find_all("div",class_="search_result_single search-2017 pb25 pt25 pl30 pr30 ")
        [links.append(link.find('a')['href']) for link in target_part]
        print("There is only one page")
        return links
```

## The test code is:

```
keyword="****"
myurl="https://www.****.com/search/os2?key={}".format(keyword)
chs_html=webscrape(login,host,values,myurl)
chs_links=getlist(keyword,login,host,values,chs_html)
targethtml=webscrape(login,host,values,chs_links[1])
```

There are total 22 links and one page containing 19 links, so it is supposed to have more than one page, if the result "There is only one page" shown up, it indicates a failure.

## Problems:

1. The login_values function is to secure my login information by combining all functions to a final function, but apparently, the username and password are still really easy to show just by `print()` command.
2. This the main problem!! Like I mentioned before, this method works randomly. By the way, what I mean not working, it is that the HTML file is only the login page instead of the searching result. I want to get a better control to make it work most of the time. I checked user-agents by print `agent` every time to see if they are relevant, and it is not! I cleared cookies with suspicious to full storage memory, and it is not.
3. There are sometimes I facing max trial error or OS error, I guess it is the error from the server I was trying to reach, is there a way I can set up a wait timer for me to prevent these errors from happening?

Comment: https://www.tianyancha.com/login doesn't work. give some link that is usable.

Comment: I can use the link provided...I don't know why it won't work for you

Comment: I am supposing that you are seeing a login page. Is that right?

Comment: I see a sorry page with `http://static.tianyancha.com/wap/images/forbidden3.png` in the body.

Comment: yes, I saw a login page, and I tried a set of different code, there is another problem showed up, which is encoding.

Comment: Sorry man, you are not helping solve your problem. there only an image in the page and you are trying to access input filelds which aren't present in the page in the first place.

Comment: I tried to use 'urllib' recently, trying to understand the basics, I'll try to use requests again, hopefully it will work this time.

Comment: I used Postman to post the data to the url you provided, but it has the same result as I commented before. Hope you will find something for an answer. I once used `urllib` with regular expressions to get to the part of the page and send `GET` requests. But sending a `POST` a data might be another business.

Comment: Hey man, I ran the same code again, and it works!!!! I have no idea why it happened. But it gave me the result I wanted

Comment: That's great! I am hoping to see your solution if you are willing to share it. And can you kinda edit the question for others to get it easily.

Comment: it seems it will work when I didn't open and log in first. OK I will combine the stuffs